# mimalloc recommended options

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, mimalloc

My application working hard with a lot of threads and small memory allocations. As result I have a lot of memory fragmentation. I tried to use **mimalloc**, but does not seen any improvements. Can anyone explain following **mimalloc** statistics (with default options) and give me any recommendations on **mimalloc** options? There is no memory leak, it has been checked with everything possible: valgrind, address sanitizer, vld, deleaker.

```
heap stats:     peak      total      freed       unit      count  
normal   1:     7.6 mb    69.6 mb    69.6 mb       8 b      9.1 m   not all freed!
normal   4:    20.7 mb    42.8 gb    42.8 gb      32 b      1.4 g   not all freed!
normal   6:    28.2 mb   814.4 mb   814.4 mb      48 b     17.7 m   not all freed!
normal   8:    18.7 mb     4.4 gb     4.4 gb      64 b     75.4 m   not all freed!
normal   9:     7.2 mb     2.9 gb     2.9 gb      80 b     39.6 m   not all freed!
normal  10:    46.6 mb   256.9 gb   256.9 gb      96 b      2.8 g   not all freed!
normal  11:     9.7 mb     3.9 gb     3.9 gb     112 b     37.7 m   not all freed!
normal  12:   102.3 mb   156.9 mb   156.9 mb     128 b      1.2 m   not all freed!
normal  13:    25.5 mb     6.2 gb     6.2 gb     160 b     41.8 m   not all freed!
normal  14:     2.0 kb     3.0 kb     2.2 kb     192 b       16     not all freed!
normal  15:    37.9 kb   453.0 mb   453.0 mb     224 b      2.1 m   ok
normal  16:    22.3 mb    43.2 gb    43.2 gb     256 b    181.3 m   not all freed!
normal  17:     5.0 kb   136.2 mb   136.2 mb     320 b    446.5 k   not all freed!
normal  18:    60.9 kb    81.9 mb    81.9 mb     384 b    223.7 k   ok
normal  19:    75.5 kb   692.5 mb   692.5 mb     448 b      1.6 m   ok
normal  21:    23.8 kb   306.5 mb   306.5 mb     640 b    502.3 k   ok
normal  23:     896 b      896 b        0 b      896 b        1     not all freed!
normal  25:     3.7 kb     5.0 kb     5.0 kb     1.2 kb       4     ok
normal  29:   301.1 mb   301.1 mb   301.1 mb     2.5 kb   123.3 k   ok
normal  30:     3.0 kb     3.0 kb     3.0 kb     3.0 kb       1     ok
normal  33:    10.0 kb    15.0 kb    15.0 kb     5.0 kb       3     ok
normal  37:    10.0 kb    10.0 kb    10.0 kb    10.0 kb       1     ok
normal  41:    20.0 kb    20.0 kb    20.0 kb    20.0 kb       1     ok
normal  45:    40.1 kb    40.1 kb    40.1 kb    40.1 kb       1     ok
normal  49:    80.3 kb    80.3 kb    80.3 kb    80.3 kb       1     ok
normal  53:   160.6 kb   160.6 kb   160.6 kb   160.6 kb       1     ok
normal  57:   321.2 kb   321.2 kb   321.2 kb   321.2 kb       1     ok
normal  61:   642.5 kb   642.5 kb   642.5 kb   642.5 kb       1     ok
normal  65:     1.2 mb     1.2 mb     1.2 mb     1.2 mb       1     ok

heap stats:     peak      total      freed       unit      count  
    normal:   593.1 mb   363.5 gb   363.5 gb       1 b              not all freed!
      huge:     2.2 m      2.2 m      2.2 m      2.2 mb       1     ok
     giant:       0 b        0 b        0 b        1 b              ok
     total:   595.4 mb   363.5 gb   363.5 gb       1 b              not all freed!
malloc requested:        317.5 gb

  reserved:   513.3 mb   514.6 mb     2.6 mb       1 b              not all freed!
 committed:   153.8 mb   155.1 mb     2.6 mb       1 b              not all freed!
     reset:     3.6 mb     1.7 gb     1.7 gb       1 b              ok
   touched:    17.3 mb     7.7 gb     7.7 gb       1 b              not all freed!
  segments:     174        179        179                           ok
-abandoned:      63         63          0                           not all freed!
   -cached:       0          0          0                           ok
     pages:     2.2 k    249.4 k    249.1 k                         not all freed!
-abandoned:     317        317          0                           not all freed!
 -extended:     1.9 m 
 -noretire:     5.4 m 
     mmaps:     344   
   commits:     2.4 k 
   threads:     341        341        341                           ok
  searches:     1.1 avg
numa nodes:       1
   elapsed:     484.597 s
   process: user: 2618.193 s, system: 136.003 s, faults: 0, reclaims: 66395, rss: 306.7 mb
heap stats:     peak      total      freed       unit      count  
normal   1:     7.6 mb    69.6 mb    69.6 mb       8 b      9.1 m   ok
normal   4:    20.7 mb    42.8 gb    42.8 gb      32 b      1.4 g   ok
normal   6:    28.2 mb   814.4 mb   814.4 mb      48 b     17.7 m   ok
normal   8:    18.7 mb     4.4 gb     4.4 gb      64 b     75.4 m   ok
normal   9:     7.2 mb     2.9 gb     2.9 gb      80 b     39.6 m   ok
normal  10:    46.6 mb   256.9 gb   256.9 gb      96 b      2.8 g   ok
normal  11:     9.7 mb     3.9 gb     3.9 gb     112 b     37.7 m   ok
normal  12:   102.3 mb   156.9 mb   156.9 mb     128 b      1.2 m   ok
normal  13:    25.5 mb     6.2 gb     6.2 gb     160 b     41.8 m   ok
normal  14:     2.4 kb     3.5 kb     4.1 kb     192 b       19     ok
normal  15:    37.9 kb   453.0 mb   453.0 mb     224 b      2.1 m   ok
normal  16:    22.3 mb    43.2 gb    43.2 gb     256 b    181.3 m   ok
normal  17:     5.3 kb   136.2 mb   136.2 mb     320 b    446.5 k   ok
normal  18:    60.9 kb    81.9 mb    81.9 mb     384 b    223.7 k   ok
normal  19:    75.5 kb   692.5 mb   692.5 mb     448 b      1.6 m   ok
normal  21:    23.8 kb   306.5 mb   306.5 mb     640 b    502.3 k   ok
normal  23:     896 b      896 b      896 b      896 b        1     ok
normal  25:     3.7 kb     5.0 kb     5.0 kb     1.2 kb       4     ok
normal  29:   301.1 mb   301.1 mb   301.1 mb     2.5 kb   123.3 k   ok
normal  30:     3.0 kb     3.0 kb     3.0 kb     3.0 kb       1     ok
normal  33:    10.0 kb    15.0 kb    15.0 kb     5.0 kb       3     ok
normal  37:    10.0 kb    10.0 kb    10.0 kb    10.0 kb       1     ok
normal  41:    20.0 kb    20.0 kb    20.0 kb    20.0 kb       1     ok
normal  45:    40.1 kb    40.1 kb    40.1 kb    40.1 kb       1     ok
normal  49:    80.3 kb    80.3 kb    80.3 kb    80.3 kb       1     ok
normal  53:   160.6 kb   160.6 kb   160.6 kb   160.6 kb       1     ok
normal  57:   321.2 kb   321.2 kb   321.2 kb   321.2 kb       1     ok
normal  61:   642.5 kb   642.5 kb   642.5 kb   642.5 kb       1     ok
normal  65:     1.2 mb     1.2 mb     1.2 mb     1.2 mb       1     ok

heap stats:     peak      total      freed       unit      count  
    normal:   593.1 mb   363.5 gb   363.5 gb       1 b              ok
      huge:     2.2 m      2.2 m      2.2 m      2.2 mb       1     ok
     giant:       0 b        0 b        0 b        1 b              ok
     total:   595.4 mb   363.5 gb   363.5 gb       1 b              ok
malloc requested:        317.5 gb

  reserved:   513.3 mb   514.6 mb   514.6 mb       1 b              ok
 committed:   154.6 mb   155.9 mb   514.6 mb       1 b              ok
     reset:     3.6 mb     1.7 gb     1.7 gb       1 b              ok
   touched:    17.4 mb     7.7 gb     7.7 gb       1 b              ok
  segments:     177        245        245                           ok
-abandoned:      64         64         64                           ok
   -cached:       0          0          0                           ok
     pages:     2.2 k    249.4 k    249.4 k                         ok
-abandoned:     318        318        318                           ok
 -extended:     1.9 m 
 -noretire:     5.4 m 
     mmaps:     346   
   commits:     2.4 k 
   threads:     345        345        345                           ok
  searches:     1.1 avg
numa nodes:       1
   elapsed:     484.601 s
   process: user: 2618.193 s, system: 136.007 s, faults: 0, reclaims: 66420, rss: 306.7 mb
```

Comment: As `mimalloc()` is not in the standard library, I recommend  tagging this question with the compiler of interest .

Comment: @chux - This is a cross-platform library, so the compiler is not important